# The work of revtex4-1 style against more recent LaTeX environments

Tags: packages

I use the miktex, the last upgrade was on April 2021. Right after that the style files for
revtex4-1 stopped to work. The Overleaf team aswers: "...the revtex4-1.cls can run into problems when run against more recent LaTeX environments".

Have anybody such problems and what to do (e.g. how to prepare the LaTeX article for needed journal) in this case?

Semenko54

Comment: overleaf doesn't use miktex and has an older latex. If you have a local problem and current latex there: if you want to stick with revtex4-1 you will to install an update manually from ctan https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1, as it is obsolete it is not installed automatically by the tex systems anymore. Better would be to switch to revtex4-2.

Comment: Thanks a lot, revtex4-2 works, but I am absolutely not sure if this is what the magazine needs  (which the log requires).